# Is this rim still safe to use?

Tags: rims, rim-brake, crack

[image]

I bought it this way without the seller noting the issue, so experience from riding with these is zero. Rims are Ritchey Girder OCRs. The crack is pretty small, but noticeable, and I will be running Maxxis DTHs on it, so I will pretty much load the inner tube with 70-80 psi or maybe even more. The crack runs unto the inside of the rim. The brake surface is still thick and deep and I doubt that it's worn out its lifespan.

I just want to know if I can still use these in the long run without compromising safety. I know a crack on a rim is stating the obvious and if I'm skeptical, it would be smart to just buy a new rim, but I'm in need of a well functioning bike as the pandemic restricts public transportation, and buying a new rim just doesn't fit my budget right now.

If I can repair these, how would I proceed? These rims are too beautiful to let go, and it would be nice if I can do something about it.

I shined a flashlight through the crack and it seems that light does not seep through it, if ever that helps. I will inspect it further to see if the crack I saw from the inside is just from the paint and not the aluminium. By any chance, if it is just a deep surface scratch, will the rim still be usable for a long time or so? If it helps, I won't be using v/u brakes.

Picture of the supposed crack in the inner part of the side wall:

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, it sounds like you are saying that it’s not just the brake surface, you can see the crack from inside the rim. I initially thought that was just a surface scratch, but if the crack goes through the entire sidewall, then that rim is indeed dead.

Comment: If you purchased a pair of these inspect the other carefully

Comment: Is it really a crack or a deep scratch? The way it thins out makes it look a bit like a scratch. Scratch would be OK. It would be strange for a crack to appear without any other signs of deformation. Scratch could come from the milling process.

Comment: @legaspoiroy try pushing it, hard with your thumbs while your fingers are braced around the rim.  It should have no more flex than the good side of the rim.    If it flexes worse, then you know its dead.  If it doesn't "feel" different, then its still inconclusive.

Comment: Kudos to the OP for including photos, both to start and to supplement the discussion. That said, it can be hard to take a good one of small details, and I can’t see inside the rim clearly. It is starting to look more like a surface scratch, though.

Comment: @WeiwenNg I think, the images are clear enough: There's a clear dark line on the inside of there rim within the marking rectangle which does not extend outside of the marking. And that line does look like the counterpart of the crack on close inspection. I guess, there was some bubble in the cast material that went into the extruder, which got stretched for form this crack. This rim should never have left the factory.

Comment: One day the bead of the tyre will push that outwards. At about a square inch of weak surface, with about 100lbs pressure. That's the end of your rim, probably your tyre, and definitely your day's ride.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica That's an excellent point - but sadly Richley warranty only covers the original purchaser, I checked.

Comment: How old are these rims?  The nearest I could find for the model was a 2009 listing, and that was a disk-brake rim.   For this to be a rim-brake rim, it has to be at least a decade old and possibly more.   Its been around, and could have suffered from crash damage or storage mishandling.    https://www.vitalmtb.com/product/guide/Rims,47/Ritchey/WCS-Girder-XC-OCR-Disc-Rim,9345    for completeness though its not yours.     Might be time to learn the art of wheelbuilding the existing hub onto a new rim ?

Answer (score 25):

Sorry, those rims are trash (or wall art).

I'd chase down the seller and demand your money back, and report them on whatever sites they were advertising on for selling items in a known dangerous state.

The crank may be small now but it will propagate in both directions and get bigger. Cracks on thin section aluminum cannot be welded as the heat will destroy the heat treatment state of the metal around the repair.

Comment: Concur - there is no paint on the outside braking track.  On the inside, there appears to be a white layer of plastic, and I'd suspect the crack is visible there.    Here's a gratuitous slow-motion shot of exactly this rim failure, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLZaITy5w8I   Had he been turning harder, he'd have gone down.

Comment: Failure modes for such a crack are a) bulging of the flange and locking the wheel in the rim brakes, or b) failure to restrain the tire and immediate blow out of the tube. Either failure mode can turn out deadly if it happens under unlucky circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately - we can't tell you what is safe and what is not.  Its your decision in the end whether to ride this rim or recycle it.  A replacement rim is cheaper than an accident, even with full cover.

If you ride it, there will always be the nagging thought in your mind "what-if it fails on the next corner?" which will decrease your overall confidence in your bike, limiting your speed and/or enjoyment.

Remember, successful rides don't mean it won't fail in the future.

---

But I've also had hard choices before, perhaps riding something that should really be replaced.

**If you, as a competent adult, choose to ride this rim, then consider these basic precautions:**

- Measure the length, accurately.  Use calipers if you can, or a steady hand with a good ruler.  Note this measurement down and date it.
- Inflate your tube/tyre to riding pressure.  Then lay your ruler's edge along the flat face, and put a torch/flashlight behind it.  Take a photo showing where light might be coming through.  Save and date this photo.
- Repeat these tests regularly.  I'd go with weekly, you might choose fortnighly, monthly, or whatever window works for you.
- **Compare** the results.  If the crack never grows, and never flexes, it may be okay.   If the crack lengthens or the sidewall is no longer flat (co-planar!) then immediately stop riding it.
- If you're out riding and applying the rear brake gives a "pulsing" feel, **immediately** release the rear brake and stop with the front brake.

If you're on a long ride, I'd check multiple times across the ride too.

**UPSHOT** Personally I'd replace it cos teeth don't grow back.  You have to make your own decision.  If you do ride it, minimise risk with vigilance.

---

Here's a rim on my own bike that failed suddenly today.

[image]

There is no sign of a crack beforehand - the rim failed while inflating tyre to around 80-90 PSI, and thankfully not while being ridden.  The only warning was a click about half-a-second before it burst.   Also fortunate I was using a track/floor pump and was not as close to the rim as a hand pump would have to be.

Here's a close up video of the crack itself.  There is no visible darkening or indication of a gradual crack.

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/6Vu1yzpUKTM